# Node.js only reloads a json file on server restart although that should happen dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a Post-form in my ejs-template that passes one object via Ajax/post without the page being reloaded. The handler in my app.js then saves the data into a data.json. All of this is working perfectly.

My only concern is that node seems to be requiring the json file only once, I have already tried using setInterval() which made no difference at all.
The desired functionality is that the server reloads the data.json after every other submit of my form. Furthermore I have an iframe where the loaded data is displayed. This should happen on the fly therefore without any refresh of the page.

Comment: If you're using `require` on a JSON file it is loaded into cache. Every subsequent require on that file will return the same data unless you reload the server.

Comment: Okay thanks. Then is there a better way to store data dynamically that is not client-specific than JSON? If one user uses the form, every other user should also see the changes instantly. Should I use sockets for this purpose?

Comment: You can always read it using fs.readFile and than use JSON.parse to create object from it. To load it dynamically in your browser just make an ajax request. Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score -1):

For your above comment socket has nothing to do with it.

To answer your question , you can keep that JSON in memory , creating that object as a global object accessible by every part of code (files).

code example ->

app.js -

```
global_json = require('../path/myJSON'); //please note that I am not using var here to make it global
//Rest of the code
```

file1.js -

```
module.exports = fun(req, res) {
    global_json.something = req.body.something;
//global_json accessible in every file
}
```

**Alternative**

If this is not the use case, then you can read and write file in every request (from post), although file reads/writes are slow but wont be the bottle neck in case of node.js server

```
function formpost(req, res) {
var data = req.body;
fs.writeFile('filename.json', JSON.stringify(data), cb);
}
```

//And same with reads

Comment: OP is trying to do the opposite - to not cache JSON in memory and load it again each time. Creating global variables is a bad practice and should be avoided.